# sl4j + async logback

Tags: java, swing, slf4j, logback

Trying to configure ascyn logging with logback and sl4j.

In code (shortened):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

logger.warn("Warning message");
```

in loogback.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%.-1level %d{yyMMdd} %d{HHmmss.SSS} [%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </layout>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>500</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </appender>        

    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

For testing I've forced to throw 10 exceptions per second.

In profiler I see AsyncAppender-Worker-Thread-1, but it always WAITING, while main thread does all work.

What have I missed?

Comment: Are you trying to understand what the async thread is doing or are you saying that you don't see your exceptions or warning messages on the console?